# I have attached a image. I am trying to get such effect on flutter. Can anyone tell how such effects are created?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am doing Flutter development. I want to add image like this and want to know how such effects or images are created. I think 3D effect is used. But I don't know how to create such image. Please help.

[![Attached Image][1]]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNiUZ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either directly create this kind of image using your picture editor (PS, Figma, Paint, anything really). Add manually a margin to your `Card` and set the Runner for it to be out of the `Card`. Then simply display the picture file in Flutter using `Image.assets(...)`.

In the case you want to programmatically create a similar image you can use a `Stack` in Flutter in order to make the runner picture overflow the card positioning manually both pictures.